# How to redirect to Invalid page if wrong URL entered but without any framework in php?

Tags: php

How can I redirect to or render an invalid page in my website if the user tries to type wrong URL which is doesn't exist. I want a common code for this as I don't used framework in website so that If a user type in action that is wrong or does not exists will redirect to page saying " The page isn't available"? I have not used any framework in my Website. So Please Give me a solution.

Comment: Is it a custom website or for example Wordpress? And what do you mean by action? If it is a custom website and user hits a page which doesn't exist 404 will show up. By action do you mean get parameters?

Comment: You normally use your webserver software to detect a HTML error 404 and redirect to an error page. If you're using Apache see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html Other webserver have similar options.

Answer (score 1):

Create a a 404.php page then write what ever you want em to see then create a .htaccess file place it on the same folder as your site

**404.php**

```
<?php
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>
  </head>
  <body>404 Error - Page Not Found!</body>
</html>
```

> You must specify the 404 HTTP response header in your custom 404 error
>   page else it would be treated as a normal page and 200 OK response
>   will be sent to client browser. The `header()` must be called before
>   any actual output is sent

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your .htaccess file, you can define a custom 404 error page.

You can follow this tutorial :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache